# Execute Operation only if Window visible

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

What I basically want is the equivalent of [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/08/29/54728.aspx) code, i.e. I have some expensive operation that I only want to do when the user can actually see the updates.

Note that this is NOT the same as just catching a `IsVisibleChanged` event, since this will only work if we really hide the window, but not if some other window covers it.

Also I'm **not** looking for code that solves the problem exactly the same way as Raymond does in C++ - I'm looking for the most idiomatic solution in WPF, as long as the result is similar that's fine by me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you are wanting a more WPF centric answer, but what you are looking for is more system level information. i.e. wether or not your window is visible or covered up by another window. I think that Raymond's idea has merit, but since Wpf hides the WndProc from you, you will need to do something like this Blog post by Andrew Eichacker on [Attaching to WndProc in WPF](http://blog.andreweichacker.com/2010/02/attaching-to-wndproc-in-wpf/) describes. You should then be able to intercept the WM_PAINT message as your link suggests.

From above link:

> In your window’s SourceInitialized event, create an HwndSource object
>   from your window’s handle. Use the AddHook method to attach an event
>   handler to all of your window’s events using the supplied function.

Comment: Yeah I knew I could just PInvoke my way through the problem, but I hoped that maybe there would be a better solution - it seems like an useful abstraction to have. Still, "can't do that" is an answer too.

Answer (score 0):

What about using Window.IsActive?

Comment: Active is not the same as visible. You can have a window visible while it's not in focus.